# Technique to model a 3D button (Image attached)

Tags: modeling

I've got this image from a skeuomorphic calculator interface and want to model it in Blender.
[image]

I was able to create this within minutes, with the following technique : Subdividing a cube multiple times and pull the face in the middle upwards with proportional editing on. Then I lowered the circle for proportional editing and lowered the middle face again.

[image]

The outcome is not exactly what I want, since the topology is round and not squared with rounded borders and stuff like this. So I was wondering if someone knows a better technique to achieve this?

Comment: Add the loopcuts (**Ctrl+R**) and place them properly to crease the shape.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, because Paul's comment above deserves to be the answer, and respectively he deserves the credit, however I'm adding a link to help you see what He's referring to. @PaulGonet, please add this as an anwer. Animation here: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrdU3.gif)

Comment: @Rick Riggs Feel free to add your answer (the solution presented in your .gif looks good). And I'll add mine. The more different answers the better :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the Text version of the Step-by-Step (please see Images below for visual reference of each step).

1. In **Object Mode** add a plane by hitting: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> **Plane**.
2. Hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter into **Edit Mode**.
3. Select all Vertices by hitting <kbd>A</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> -> **Only Faces**.
4. Select all Vertices by hitting <kbd>A</kbd>. (**NOTE: Repeat the Next Steps 3 Times) Hit <kbd>W</kbd> -> <kbd>S</kbd>.
5. Add a circle mesh by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> **Circle**. Next scale it down by hitting <kbd>S</kbd> -> <kbd>0</kbd> -> <kbd>.</kbd> -> <kbd>5</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

6. Ensure all Vertices are selected (<kbd>A</kbd> to toggle - you will probably have to hit this twice at this point), then hit <kbd>W</kbd> -> <kbd>E</kbd>, this will invoke the **Bridge Edge Loops** command to fill the gap between the rectangular mesh perimeter, and the inner circular mesh perimeter.

[image]

7. Hover your cursor over one of the newly created connection edges (eg. about the mid-point on an edge that spans from the perimeter plane to the perimeter circle) and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Next move your mouse until you have the desired shape, then <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd>.

[image]

Refer to

[image]

for how to manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: please have the text be part of the answer and not a picture. Text within an image cannot be searched or accessed by search engines. Use the images as support for the text not otherwise.

Comment: Sometimes I feel, that the Blender stackexchange is on another level compared with the others.. These answers are always on point and great!

Comment: @cegaton I will circle back around and get this one covered, once I can get to something other than my phone.